# Passing connectionString to ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to pass a connectionString to ApplicationDbContext but it is determined from some details passed to the login page, however I can only work out how to pass it from the Startup.Auth.cs page.

My Web Application basically does a lookup in a database to work out which DB the user will connect to. I need to pass the connectionString either from passing it in the Login page or to store it somewhere and retrieve it in the Startup.Auth.cs, this is what I have so far:

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ApplicationDbContext.Create("ConnectionString"));
```

Thanks

Comment: If you don't know the connection string when you configure auth, then that's the wrong time to be setting up the context.

Comment: ok thanks, yes I understand but I cannot work out how this can be setup somewhere else?

Comment: Well if you don't know what connection string to use until after the user has logged in, then don't create the context until after the user has logged in. You can create it on demand if you wish, and just store the connection string (or connection string name) somewhere.

Comment: oh perhaps I didn't explain it quite that clearly. My application does a lookup initially on a generic database, and looks up the domain name the user is using to login. It then returns the database name they will connect to. So I am querying a db before the authentication actually happens. The authentication then happens against the database returned

Comment: I understood that, and it doesn't change what I've said. You know the generic database info ahead of time, and you already know how to connect to that one, right? It's just the 2nd database that you won't know until after authentication, right?

Comment: Yes but at the moment there is no real authentication on the first database, the real authentication will happen on the second database.

Comment: Do you have an example of creating it on demand? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91778/discussion-between-realtek-and-mason).

Comment: To create it on demand, just do a new ApplicationDbContext when you need it.

Comment: oh lol thank you, it works. I did this right at the beginning but got sidetracked and never tested it. Thanks, put it as an answer and I will accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the ApplicationDbContext until you need to, at which point you should know the connection string to use.